# How can I reset the environment to the default for a user when running program as that user?

Tags: linux, environment-variables, language-agnostic, libc

I'm trying to run a program in Rust using libc as another user.

```rust
nix::unistd::setuid(uid).unwrap();
```

If I `fork` and `exec` a process which runs `printenv`, the environment does not change. How can I reset the environment to the default for a user?

Comment: `fork & exec` - so exec with new environment. [execve](https://docs.rs/nix/0.9.0/nix/unistd/fn.execve.html)

Comment: How can I get the "new" environment?

Comment: Users don't have default environments. This is why so many people have problems with cron jobs, remote logins and such that run in a different context from e.g. their graphical login

Comment: I see. So when for example I use `su -`, how is su populating the environment variables?

Comment: `su` is not populating environment variables, the shell that su runs is populating them. If you run `su` under `strace` you can see that it calls `execve("/bin/bash", ["-bash" ....]` internally. Most of the environment variables are set by the shell, not by `su`. You can do the same as `su` does - run the shell, and then, inside the shell, run the command `printenv`.

Answer (score -2):

With [`nix::unistd::execve()`](https://docs.rs/nix/0.9.0/nix/unistd/fn.execve.html)'s third argument `env`, you have full control over the next processes environment. Also see [`exec(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html).

Comment: This answer is fairly bare-bones and doesn't really demonstrate how to solve the problem.